# How to modify Tomcat server configuration to modify the browser URL for a particular IP address

Tags: tomcat, filter, server

I have already restricted my Tomcat server from listening to IPv4 addresses. My application supports only IPv6 address. But for a particular IPv4 address how to redirect the URL to a particular IPv6 address?

Comment: Can you please give an example of what you're trying to do? You want a process that refuses IPv4 connections to ... respond to an IPv4 connection? This sounds more like a DNS thing than anything else. Do you expect clients to use IPv4 addresses to contact your service directly?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Socat Tool

And example command which forwards the traffic from all incoming

Install:

```
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install socat
```

Switch on root user and run:

```
# nohup socat TCP4-LISTEN:8080,fork,su=nobody TCP6:[2001:db8:a0b:12f0::1]:8080 &
```

**Change IPv6** in the command above to yours.

After that, traffic will be redirected from IPv4 port 8080, to IPv6 port 8080.
if your Tomcat server listens on other port, adjust the command.

Reference:
https://ef.gy/forwarding-ipv4-to-ipv6